# Python Error code: IndexError: index error list index out of range

Tags: python, random, indexing

I'm trying to write a function in Python that simulates a horse race. While there's no winner, it clears the screen, shows the list of horses (all have index starting at zero). Then, on the line I've marked, the code messes up. 
I get the index error list out of range. I'm trying to randomly pick a horse (randomly pick an index number) and add 1 to the value. But I can't seem to figure it out!!

```
while (no_winner):

    os.system("cls")

    print(horses)

    # randomly assign a horse to step forward
    rando = random.randint(1, HORSE_NUM)
    horses[rando] += 1  #######PROBLEM

    # if the horse exceeds the finish line, he wins
    if (steps > FINISH_LINE):

        winner = horses[index]
        no_winner = False
```

Comment: randints upper bound is inclusive so you need to go -1 but list indexes also start at 0 so you may also want to just use ` random.randint(0,  HORSE_NUM -1 )` to allow the horse at index 0 to be picked. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint

Answer (score 1):

random.randint() is inclusive, so if you get a random integer that is equal to HORSE_NUM it will be out of bounds. try

```
rando = random.randint(0, HORSE_NUM - 1)
```